# How in the world does Windows File Explorer sort by name?

Tags: windows, file, sorting

Just once I'd like someone from Microsoft to say, "That seems weird.  It looks like you might lose your files.  I'll log a bug for that."

In what universe does 5 come before 4?

[image]

Comment: That's because 25 comes before 245.  (As a human, I can spot that those filenames are probably hexadecimal and should presumably be sorted on that basis.  But that's perhaps a bit much to ask a computer.)

Answer (score 7):

Courtesy @RaymondChen's [Windows Confidential: The Evolution of Sorting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh475812.aspx):

> ...when Windows 95 sorted file names for display in Windows Explorer, it would put file139 ahead of file20. This is perfectly logical from a computer programmer’s point of view. It’s also completely counter-intuitive to normal human beings—thus proving that computer programmers are not normal human beings.
>
> In Windows XP, Microsoft updated the Windows Explorer sorting algorithm to be more in line with what normal human beings expect. It treated digits in file names as numbers instead of sequences of characters. While this improved sorting for most people, there were cases where this change resulted in some surprises.
>
> One example that recurred frequently was file names containing hex values. Under the new number-based sorting, Windows Explorer assumed that a file named “1040A” should sort slightly after “1040,” and nowhere near a file named “103F2.” **If for whatever reason you’re in the habit of viewing folders full of files whose names are hex values, you can set the policy “Turn off numerical sorting in Windows Explorer.”** This policy changes sorting back to the way it was in versions of Windows prior to Windows XP—namely, character-by-character.

Ironically enough, this was known as "*intuitive file sorting*" when the feature was introduced back in Windows XP. It can be turned off by setting local policies (as **highlighted** above) or by editing the registry - see [How to Enable or Disable Numerical Sorting in Windows Explorer](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/88153-numerical-sorting-windows-explorer-enable-disable.html).

Comment: Well.  Sorry about being off topic.  Not sure there are a lot of "normal" people out there generating file names based on hex counts, but I guess Windows File Explorer is about as general purpose as you can get.  (Of course, no one who isn't a programmer would have any idea how to answer this question but that is another story...)

Comment: The reason I posted (tried to post) the image, was to show cases in question.  I would have thought an "answer" would be ambitious enough to explain why B607 comes before BA2A but C245 comes after C25A.  (Yes I know there are numbers and words, and those hex numbers are just so confusing.)  It is hard to come up with a workaround when the behavior in question appears to be random.

Comment: This is a problem with GUID or UUID based filenames.  Can't scroll list, had to search.