# Loop through files in a numeric order (Like on Windows Explorer)

Tags: windows, sorting, batch-file

I have a group of files that I want to be sorted numerically with FOR command like this:

```
FOR %%G IN (*.pdf) DO (
ECHO %%G
)
```

Is there any way to have :

```
1.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf
...
10.pdf
11.pdf
```

Instead of :

```
1.pdf
10.pdf
11.pdf
12.pdf
...
2.pdf
21.pdf
```

Like they are ordered on the Windows Explorer?
 [My files ordered on Windows Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl08L.png)

Comment: That's a [feature of Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39048747/1889329). I'm not aware of any way to get that outside of Explorer (unless you replicate the sorting algorithm yourself).

Comment: You could do `for /L %%I in (1,1,100) do @if exist "%%~I.pdf" echo/%%~I`...

Comment: The easiest way would be to stick a 0 in front of the first nine numbers.

Comment: @SomethingDark: That's only easy, if you can easily change the code of the generator. And the fix will break all over again, once you hit `100.pdf`.

Comment: @Blumer, over on DosTips we have two scripts that help with sorting files numerically.  [Sortn.bat](https://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.SortTextWithNumbers) & [Jsort](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595)

Comment: Thank you for the answers! 
@aschipfl I can't do that since some of my files have text after the leading numbers; for example "10 Abri.pdf" like I show it on the Windows Explorer capture I uploaded.

Comment: @SomethingDarkI just finished a script that adds zeros at the beggining of the files' names, so that they all have four digits, for example : "0001.pdf" "0002.pdf" "0010.pdf" "0100.pdf" following  your idea, thanks
But since it requires changing files' names,I think I'll try Squashman's script

Comment: So what about: `for /L %%I in (1,1,100) do @for /F "delims=" %%J in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:N "%%~I*" ^| findstr /V /I "^%%~I[^0123456789]*.pdf$"') do @echo/%%~J`

Comment: It sorts all the files except the then first ones

Comment: Can you please explain to me how does exactly `in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:N "%%~I*" ^| findstr /V /I "^%%~I[^0123456789]*.pdf$"') ` work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implements shellsort using API call `StrCmpLogicalW`

`StrCmpLogicalW` treats numbers in strings as if they were numbers.

To use

```
logicalsort < "C:\Windows\System32\NetSetupMig.log"
```

To compile run this batch file in same directory as vb file.

```
REM LogicalSort.bat
REM This file compiles LogicalSort.vb to LogicalSort.exe
REM LogicalSort.exe sorts lines from stdin and writes to stdout. Numbers in strings are sorted as numbers.
REM To use 
REM LogicalSort < Inputfile.txt > Outputfile.txt
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:exe /out:"%~dp0\LogicalSort.exe" "%~dp0\LogicalSort.vb"
pause
```

---

```
'LogicalSort.vb
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 
Public Module MyApplication  

Public Declare UNICODE Function StrCmpLogicalW Lib "Shlwapi" (ByVal FirstStr as String, ByVal SecondStr As String) as Integer

Sub Main
    Dim MyArray(15) as String
    Dim TempStr As String
    Dim Line As Object
    TempStr = ""
    Line=Console.readline
    Do Until Line = Nothing
        TempStr = TempStr & vbcrlf & Line
        Line=Console.readline
    Loop
    MyArray = Split(TempStr, vbcrlf)

    Sort(MyArray)
End Sub

Sub Sort(MyArray() As String)
    Dim TempVal As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim GapSize As Integer
    Dim CurPos As Integer
    Dim FirstLine As Integer
    Dim LastLine As Integer
    Dim NumLines As Integer
    FirstLine = LBound(MyArray)
    LastLine = UBound(MyArray)
    NumLines = LastLine - FirstLine + 1
    Do
        GapSize = GapSize * 3 + 1
    Loop Until GapSize > NumLines
    Do
        GapSize = GapSize \ 3
        For i = (GapSize + FirstLine) To LastLine
            CurPos = i
            TempVal = MyArray(i)
            Do While CompareResult( MyArray(CurPos - GapSize),TempVal)
                MyArray(CurPos) = MyArray(CurPos - GapSize)
                CurPos = CurPos - GapSize
                If (CurPos - GapSize) < FirstLine Then Exit Do
            Loop
            MyArray(CurPos) = TempVal
        Next
    Loop Until GapSize = 1

    For each thing in MyArray
        Console.writeline(thing)
    Next
 End Sub

Private Function CompareResult(Value1 As String, Value2 As String) as Boolean
    CompareResult = (StrCmpLogicalW(Value1, Value2) = 1)
End Function


End Module
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo Unsorted:
for %%A in (*.pdf) do echo %%A

echo.
echo Sorted:
(
    for %%G in (*.pdf) do @(
        set "file=          %%~G"
        call set "file=%%file:~-14%%"
        call echo %%file%%
    )
) | for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('sort') do @echo %%A
```

Pads each filename with 10 spaces and then trims to last 14 characters
which should be within the 32 bit number range. It is piped to a
for loop to sort which gets them in order like explorer. The
`tokens=*` option removes the leading spaces. `call set` and
`call echo` expands the doubled percentage variables inside a code
block which saves using delayed expansion.

Output:

```
Unsorted:
1.pdf
11.pdf
2.pdf
22.pdf

Sorted:
1.pdf
2.pdf
11.pdf
22.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
But I can't do like that since some of my files are containing test after the leading number. For example : "16   Bras de Fer.pdf"

Comment: @Blumer, make the substring bigger then.

Comment: The code was created with 32 bit numbered filenames as the target files, though the same method can be used on any string. You can increase the padding `10` and adjust the size of the trim `14` for the sort. `sort` works by the character table and is not limited to only numbers. A space is the lowest character on the ASCII table except for control characters and should give correct results.

Answer (score 2):

Try this not so complex solution for a full natural sort support with arbitrary file names with any length and combination.

```bat
@echo Off
setlocal

:: Static Parameter - Max Leading Digits in File Names
:: Theoretical upper limit is 255
:: May affect performance if set to larger numbers unnecessarily
set "MaxLeadDigits=10"
if "%~1"=="/NaturalSort" (
   call :/NaturalSort %2
   exit /b
)

:: Literal Pattern for Natrual Sort Test
set Pattern="33 some.pdf", "2_Another_with_underline.pdf", "# should come first.pdf"
set Pattern=%Pattern%, "2 another with arbitrary longer name also with numbers 54 14.pdf"
set Pattern=%Pattern%, "1.pdf", "1 one another.pdf" ,  "Zodiac.pdf", "03.pdf", "20.pdf"
set Pattern=%Pattern%, "21449AA.pdf", "214490A.pdf", "10 other.pdf", "3.pdf"

:: **Example Patterns**
:: set Pattern="*.pdf"
:: set Pattern="*.*"
:: set Pattern="C:\Windows\*.exe", "C:\Windows\*.log", "C:\Windows\*.txt"
:: set Pattern="*.pdf", "*.txt", "USERPROFILE\Desktop\*.doc"

call "%~f0" /NaturalSort Pattern|for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%E in ('sort') do @echo(%%F
pause
exit /b

:: Explorer like natural sort routine
:/NaturalSort <PatternVar>
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "TS="  Trailing Spaces
set "LZ="  Leading Zeros
for /L %%A in (1,1,%MaxLeadDigits%) do (
    call set "TS=%%TS%% %=KeepTheSpace=%"
    call set "LZ=0%%LZ%%"
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Pattern=!%~1!"
if not defined Pattern set "Pattern=*"
endlocal & set ^"Pattern=%Pattern%^"
for %%A in (%Pattern%) do (
    set "FileName=%%~nxA"
    call :ExtractLeadNum LN FileName
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if defined LN (
        set "SortPrefix=%LZ%!LN!"
        set "SortPrefix=!SortPrefix:~-%MaxLeadDigits%!"
    ) else (
        set "SortPrefix=!FileName!%TS%"
        set "SortPrefix=!SortPrefix:~0,%MaxLeadDigits%!"
    )
    echo(!SortPrefix!:!FileName!
    endlocal
)
exit /b

:ExtractLeadNum <RtnVar> <StringVar>
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "String=!%~2!"
endlocal & set "String=%String%"
for /F "tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%G in ("%String%") do set "Garbage=%%G"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined Garbage (
    set "Garbage=!Garbage: =!"
    for /L %%N in (0,1,9) do if defined Garbage set "Garbage=!Garbage:%%N=!"
)
endlocal & set "Garbage=%Garbage%"
for /F "delims=%Garbage% %=KeepTheSpace=%" %%N in ("0%String%") do set "LeadNum=%%N"
endlocal & set "%~1=%LeadNum:~1%" & exit /b
```

--OUTPUT--

```
# should come first.pdf 
1 one another.pdf 
1.pdf 
2 another with arbitrary longer name also with numbers 54 14.pdf 
2_Another_with_underline.pdf 
03.pdf 
3.pdf 
10 other.pdf 
20.pdf 
33 some.pdf 
21449AA.pdf 
214490A.pdf 
Zodiac.pdf
```

At heart of this method is `:ExtractLeadNum` routine which will extract leading numbers from arbitrary file names with any length.

The `:/NaturalSort` routine looks into each file name to see if it begins with numbers then extract the leading numbers by `:ExtractLeadNum` routine then pads the number with zeros up to the length specified by `MaxLeadDigits` parameter and prefixes the file name with this new padded number so when applying alphabetical sort to this new name it causes the padded numbers with less value to be sorted numerically.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to perform a 'natural sort', there are possible workarounds, but those are very dependent upon the data being sorted.

For filenames which begin with numbers, as in your screenshot, padding can be used.

Here's an example:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("1.pdf"
    "10  Abri.pdf"
    "11.pdf"
    "12  R‚sultat du test.pdf"
    "13  Lettre.pdf"
    "14  Tƒche m‚nagŠre.pdf"
    "15  Faire du v‚lo … deux.pdf"
    "16  Bras de Fer.pdf"
    "17  Rˆve.pdf"
    "18  Test de courage.pdf"
    "19  Question.pdf"
    "2.pdf"
    "20  Comparer sa taille.pdf"
    "21  Changement de places.pdf"
    "22.pdf"
    "23.pdf"
    "24.pdf"
    "25.pdf"
    "26  Poursuite.pdf"
    "3.pdf"
    "4.pdf"
    "5.pdf"
    "6.pdf"
    "7.pdf"
    "8.pdf"
    "9.pdf") Do For /F "UseBackQ" %%B In ('%%~nA'
    ) Do Set "_=?00%%B" & Call Set "%%_:~,1%%%%_:~-3%%=%%~A"
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set ? 2^>Nul') Do Echo "%%B"
Pause
```

*Note:
The filenames may look a little strange because they use the character set from the Terminal font. This is intended to make it easier for those not using specific codepages etc. to copy and test without making adjustments.*
In your case, you could test it using `*.pdf` instead of listing the files as I did.
e.g.

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (*.pdf) Do For /F %%B In ("%%~nA"
) Do Set "_=?00%%B" & Call Set "%%_:~,1%%%%_:~-3%%=%%A"
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set ? 2^>Nul') Do Echo "%%B" 
Pause
```

You would need to adjust this solution depending upon the number of characters in the leading number too.
There are many caveats with this workaround, one likely problem being that the variable environment will only accept a limited number of characters, so if there are many files you could easily hit the limit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
It worked perfectly, but I couldn't fully understand how this script works...
Does it work as it is now with >99 leading numbers?
And can you please explain to me what does the commands
  `Call Set "%%_:~,1%%%%_:~-3%%=%%A"` and
  `For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set ? 2^>Nul') Do Echo "%%B"`
do precisely?

Comment: I will provide an example which you can work through yourself. Given the following file name, `19  Question.pdf`, the second `For` loop uses, `%%~nA`, i.e. `"19  Question"`, which is split at the default whitespace character, returning only the default first token, `19`. That is temporarily `Set` as a variable, `%_%` to the value, `?0019` and further `Set` as a new variable named as the first character, `?`+the last three characters, `019` of the temporary variable, to the value of the filename. The final `For` loop just `Echo`es all variables whose names begin with `?` which output sorted.