# How to list the file in current directory alphabetically in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a script in .bat file as follow :

```
for  %%f in (*.pdf) do DoSth %%f

@pause
```

This script will process the pdf files in current directory one by one but not in any order.

Is there any way to force to process the file in alphabetically order ?

Regards,

Comment: Where is your evidence of this? On NTFS files are stored in alphabetical order. That is so binary search can be used to find them.

Comment: `for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "*.pdf"') do ...` should force alphabetic order independent on the file system; on an NTFS drive your code should already return sorted items; on a FAT drive the order with your code would be kind of random; so what do you actually have?

Comment: Please note that alphabetical order means that `10` will always be processed before `2` or `9`. If your `.pdf` files use numbers like this then I'd suggest you use a different scripting language or third party utility.

Comment: If that is the case see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672351/loop-through-files-in-a-numeric-order-like-on-windows-explorer.