# How to list files using DIR or similar tool by alphanumeric in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

How to list my files as `1`, `2`, `3` … `11`, `12`, `13` using `DIR` or similar?

I am having problems automating my batch program because the program keeps on messing up listing numbers.

Any other tool is welcome, as long as it's applicable in batch.

My output:

```
dir /b /a-d "..\test\*.jpg
(1).jpg
(10).jpg
(11)..jpg
(12).jpg
(2)..jpg
(3).jpg
(4).jpg
(5)..jpg
(6).jpg
(7).jpg
(8)..jpg
(9).jpg
```

I want it to output as this:

```
dir /b /a-d "..\test\*.jpg
(1).jpg
(2)..jpg
(3).jpg
(4).jpg
(5)..jpg
(6).jpg
(7).jpg
(8)..jpg
(9).jpg
(10).jpg
(11)..jpg
(12).jpg
```

Comment: This is not possible with a simple `dir` command line; `dir` without the `/O` option usually returns the items as they are reported from the file system (I guess it's NTFS since the list seems to be alphabetically sorted); using `dir /O:N` wouldn't change anything here since this also applies alphabetic sorting; what you are looking for is alpha-numeric sorting, so numbers are specifically recognised...

Comment: @aschipfl Any other alternative that can be used on Windows specifically? I don't really mind other way as long as it exist on Windows. My easy fix is to append 0's to single digit number.

Comment: @SazeimSaheem, please change your question then, as it clearly states, **"using `DIR`"**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672351/loop-through-files-in-a-numeric-order-like-on-windows-explorer/56122298?r=SearchResults#56122298. You need LogicalSort. Not in the `dir` or `sort` command.

Comment: @SazeimSaheem, I see you've edited your question, but have still insisted that answers must use the `DIR` command. Is that what you must have?

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the question link. I was trying to find this exact question, but I don't know the correct wording. I'm going to keep this question open because I think it makes much more sense to search it this way.

Comment: @Compo Not exactly. I only need it to be in a single standalone batch file if possible.

Comment: Sazeim that makes sense. Then this question should be marked as a dup of the other so people finding this one will find the other one easily.

Comment: I've modified the question body for you to match that in your title, and therefore remove the rigid stipulation of using only the `DIR` command. *In future, @SazeimSaheem, please make the modifications yourself.*

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Windows [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) capabilities, you could augment the list by preceding every line with the number from the file name padded with zeros to the left (so they are of a fixed width) and a separator that cannot appear in file names, use `sort` for alphabetic sorting (which leads to the same result for fixed-width numbers) and remove the temporary prefix then ‐ like this, for example:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~1"                      & rem // (root directory; `%~1` is first argument)
set "_MASK=(*).jpg"                  & rem // (pattern to search for files)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to a temporary file)

rem // Write to temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    rem // Read output of `dir` command line and loop through the returned file names:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "%_ROOT%\%_MASK%"') do (
        rem // Store current file name:
        set "FILE=%%F"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of `!` (just in case):
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Extract number (beginning from second character position) and pad it:
        set "NUM=!FILE:~1!" & set /A "NUM+=0" & set "NUM=0000000000!NUM!"
        rem // Output left-zero-padded number plus `|` plus original file name:
        echo(!NUM:~-10!^|!FILE!
        endlocal
    )
)
rem // Let `sort` bring the list in alphabetic order and loop through the lines:
for /F "tokens=2 delims=|" %%L in ('sort "%_TMPF%"') do (
    rem // Return the original file name and ignore everything in front of `|`:
    echo(%%L
)
rem // Clean up the temporary file:
del "%_TMPF%"

endlocal
exit /B
```