# Confused by sorting in Windows explorer and other tools

Tags: windows, columnsorting

I have a file list. It is "sorted by name" in windows explorer as:

```
20180714_1502 - 134.JPG
20180714_1548 - 143.JPG
20180714_1727 - 150.JPG
20180714_112154.jpg
20180714_112203.jpg
20180714_112229.jpg
..
20180714_183629.jpg
20180714_183637.jpg
20180714_183645.jpg
```

Where I would expect that it (the first part) would be sorted as:

```
20180714_1502 - 134.JPG
20180714_1548 - 143.JPG
20180714_1727 - 150.JPG
20180714_183629.jpg
20180714_183637.jpg
20180714_183645.jpg
```

Can anyone explain what the idea behind this MS ordering is?
I have read some articles about natural sorting. What is natural at the MS way of sorting?
There is at least a difference with the way different tools (like Total Commander) does the sorting, leading to confusion and errors.

Comment: 1502 is less than 112154.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048747/how-in-the-world-does-windows-file-explorer-sort-by-name

Answer (score 0):

Basic sorting functions like `strcmp` just compares one character at the time. Explorer uses [`StrCmpLogicalW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw):

> Digits in the strings are considered as numerical content rather than text. This test is not case-sensitive.